# GitLab Problems

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

I have my own instance of GitLab running on a server. I noticed that GitLab uses Nginx as a server but our web apps run on Apache, so I set up Apache alongside it and it was running great. I changed the port on Apache to 8000 and set up my virtual hosts and everything. Yesterday I updated the MySQL from version 8.x to MariaDB. The issue comes in that the Apache server didn't log any of my errors to the error_log file so I changed the permissions, but now after doing that I got an error on GitLab that said that GitLab had a problem loading my repositories. I checked the /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production_json.log and found no issues. I tried to reconfigure and was met with more errors like

```
Error executing action `run` on resource 'bash[migrate gitlab-rails database]'
  ================================================================================
  
  Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
  ------------------------------------
  Command execution failed. STDOUT/STDERR suppressed for sensitive resource
```

Now I installed a new instance on a Debian server and it works fine, but when I copy the files from the other server to this one I can't reconfigure or anything. Is there anything I can do or is it beyond repair and if it is beyond repair, is there any way I can get my backed up repositories back into a new instance? I did copy the repo files in /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories over to the new instance, but to no avail. It doesn't show my repos there.

When I ran the gitlab-rake db:migrate:status command this is what I got:

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/log/application_json.log
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/logger.rb:36:in `new'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/logger.rb:36:in `build'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/multi_destination_logger.rb:10:in `block in debug'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/multi_destination_logger.rb:10:in `each'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/multi_destination_logger.rb:10:in `debug'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/active_record_lifecycle.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/active_record_lifecycle.rb:7:in `block in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/cluster/lifecycle_events.rb:77:in `on_worker_start'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/active_record_lifecycle.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate:status => db:load_config => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace
```

Comment: I don't run any GItLab servers and have never installed GitLab, but this looks like a basic permissions problem. Permissions on web servers (https) are tricky because web servers have to defend against intrusions, so there's not just the underlying file system permissions (though these matter), there are also web-server-level settings. Reading *all* the server-side logs tends to be important to find out what's going on.

Comment: Meanwhile, from a few other posts, I gather that GItLab stores the underlying repositories deep in the data directories somewhere. Look for places where there are files named `HEAD` (all caps) as those will generally be your repository directory. For instance, `find . -name HEAD -print` (modern `find` doesn't need `-print` but I tend to use it out of habit here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it fixed.

```
 1. sudo -u git mkdir -p /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repository-import-$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")
 2. sudo cp -r /backup/gitlab/git-data/repositories/@hashed/ /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repository-import-$(date "+%Y-%m-%d)
 3. sudo chown -R git:root /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/
 4. sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:import:repos["/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repository-import-$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")/ruben/intranet"]
 5. sudo rm -rf /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repository-import-$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")/
 6. Repeat for as many repos as necessary
```

Sample output:

```
 * Created ef2d127de37b942baad06145e54b0c619a1f22327b2ebbcfbec78f5564afe39d (/ef2d127de37b942baad06145e54b0c619a1f22327b2ebbcfbec78f5564afe39d)
```

This just doesn't get your issues back. If anyone knows where all the data for the repositories are, please let me know.

Comment: So sudo was missing. Good feedback. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Most GitLab commands are executed as root, as illustrated in [issues 4264](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/issues/4264).

Try

```
sudo gitlab-rake db:migrate:status
```